# How should I reinstall Windows? (Maybe repair)

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, file-transfer

My Windows files are corrupted so I think that I can't repair it normally, so can someone wither suggest something that can repair windows with access to just the files since I can't boot my PC with the windows in the drive.

I used a program to install windows onto a USB and that's how I'm able to access the files, so can someone either suggest a way to repair windows (In this circumstance) and keep personal files or how I would be able to backup or copy the personal files the import them if I was to do a clean installation of windows on the drive.

To summarise what I have/haven't access to:

- all of  the files in the drive
- a bootable  windows using USB
- external hard drive
- laptop
- I can't boot windows using the original drive

I tried to list all what I have access to so that it  can maybe present more options for what I can do.

Comment: You should backup your files and then just simply reinstall Windows.  You cannot perform a repair install from outside of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a [full disk image](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/backup-your-computer-by-making-an-image-of-your-hard-drive/) of your drive with any of the the many free tools available. For example, on another PC, create a [Macrium Reflect rescue USB](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), which contains WinPE or WinRE operating system (OS). Then boot the inoperative PC from that, and create a **verified** disk image on the external USB drive. This image allows you to get back data should anything go wrong, later.
2. From the other, working, PC, [download the Windows 10 ISO using the Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), and put it on another USB flash drive of a least 8 GB size.
3. Using the [Windows 10 installation USB, boot the bad PC](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/boot-or-repair-windows-10-using-the-installation-media) and select  “Repair your computer,” keeping files.

Hopefully, that will reinstall Windows 10, keeping all installed software, preferences you've set, and data files. **However,** [Murphy](https://www.wearethemighty.com/mighty-history/murphys-law-amazing-dr-stapp/) has taught us, [if things can go wrong, they will do so](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efgandon/miscellaneous/murphy/). *Ergo*, with a disk image, even if the HDD or SSD is going bad, you can get back the original *recoverable* data.